# Moderator Flag Dashboard - Handling for NAA and VLQ flag

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

I would like to have a feature added to the moderator flag dashboard.

When a **VLQ** or **NAA** flag is shown there, have an advanced option to the *DELETE* button, to show the same option than is shown inside the review queue's DELETE button.

An example, when I see a VLQ or a NAA flag I can delete from within the moderator flag dashboard. But when I go inside my site review's queue for a VLQ, I can choose an auto-comment to add, related to the action I take from there.

A example; that answer that I deleted via the review queue;

[image]

It had two flags cast on it, a NAA and a VLQ. I chose to add a comment, but it would be nice to have the same option in the moderator flag dashboard, as the delete option in the moderator dashboard just deletes without the possibility to add a comment.

Answer (score 5):

While this would certainly be a useful feature (also for all users using the regular Q&A pages), I have a workaround: I'm currently using the [AutoReviewComments userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061) which offers more or less the same options. The script works from the regular Q&A pages, the review queues but just as well from the flag dashboard.

It comes out of the box with some comments similar to the canned ones offered by the Low Quality Posts review queue, e.g.

> Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

for link-only answers, and you can edit them or add your own.

Answer (score 4):

The AutoReviewComments script mentioned in another answer is one workaround.  Another workaround -- and you might like this for other moderation reasons too! -- is the [Flag TOC script](https://github.com/Shog9/flagtools), which augments the in-page reporting in some useful ways:

[image: review link added to flag info]

You can tell at a glance whether the post is currently in review, and you can go directly to the review if you prefer to handle it that way.  That's faster than going through either the timeline or the mod-menu review history.